# Installing Data Interoperability when already authorized on ArcGIS Administrator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, installation, arcgis-license-manager, data-interoperability

If data interoperability is authorized on ArcGIS Administrator but is not yet installed, how does one do so in ArcGIS 10.2.2?

I have the license, now how do I get the extension? I have already checked the Customize menu and data interoperability is not listed. Nor can I find it doing a very thorough search in Windows Explorer. My license has not expired, but I cannot figure out how to install the darn thing!

I forgot to say that I am looking for the executable file that installs the extension. Online help has just said that it is in my "media file".

Comment: I forgot to say that I am looking for the executable file that installs the extension. Online help has just said that it is in my "media file". Not helpful enough.

Answer (score 6):

You need to run the separate installer for the ESRI Data Interop extension.  It should be located on the ESRI installation media, whether that is the physical DVD, or the ISO file.

1. Find the `DataInterop` directory.
   [image: ESRI Install media - Data Interop directory]
2. Run the `Setup.exe` file within that directory.
   [image: Data Interop - Setup.exe]
3. You should then be able to go into **Extensions** in the **Customize** directory and activate the Data Interoperability extension.

For future reference, here is the help documentation for installing the Data Interoperability extension from Esri:

[Installing the Data Interoperability Extension](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Installing_the_Data_Interoperability_extension/004m00000029000000/)

**[EDIT]** - That is an odd error to be receiving. Just as a final check, open up ArcMap and go to the `About Arcmap` item under the Help menu. What version do you have listed there? If it is not 10.2.2 also, then you need to ensure you have all of your software installed to the 10.2.2 level. If it does list that version number, then it is time to call ESRI Support and have them do a desktop sharing to help figure out the problem. You are undoubtedly paying for maintenance, may as well take advantage of it!

Comment: I followed both of your instructions and found the download on ESRI's web site. I received an error:

Comment: "http://i.imgur.com/0XM7HEs.png"

Comment: I am not sure how to make the desktop that I have already licensed and downloaded communicate with the data interoperability extension I successfully downloaded but have not been able to run.

Comment: That is an odd error to be receiving.  Just as a final check, open up ArcMap and go to the `About Arcmap` item under the Help menu.  What version do you have listed there?  If it is not 10.2.2 also, then you need to ensure you have all of your software installed to the 10.2.2 level.  If it does list that version number, then it is time to call ESRI Support and have them do a desktop sharing to help figure out the problem.  You are undoubtedly paying for maintenance, may as well take advantage of it!

Comment: There are two other things to try AFTER trying Get Spatial's instructions(ESRI support takes ages to get back to me usually). First Run the ESRI.exe from the root and try to install the extension using that method (this rules out it being a bug with the install file). Second there is sometimes a check for earlier versions/uninstall earlier versions button one the first page when you run "esri.exe" so try that out last.

Answer (score 2):

This installation can be accessed through the "My ESRI" portal. Normally you would download all the items required at once and so they would be present in the "media" which is mentioned in the documentation you have listed.

I'm unsure of your situation but it sounds like your installations are managed through IT or some other entity. In this case you have three options.

1. Run the ArcGIS for desktop installation again and you will see in on the first page a button labeled "Setup" next to "ArcGIS Data Interoperability for Desktop". The installation file would be named ESRI.exe and should be about 5-6GB in size.
2. find the person with the My ESRI account and get them to download the extension or point you to where the installation file is.
3. Create your own account by going here http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-desktop/free-trial and you should gain access to the installation file by adding the 60 day trial. NOTE: you may not need the 60 day trial but you definitely need the ESRI Account.